# how to create a HTTP-1.0 request by net.socket or http.request?

Tags: sockets, node.js, http-1.0

I want to create a HTTP-1.0 request by net.socket or http.request but I have a problem with this code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
   host:'google.com',
   method: 'CONNECT',
   path: 'google.com:80',
   port: 80
};

var req = http.request(options);
req.end();

req.on('connect', function(res, socket, head) {
   socket.write('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n' +
                'Host: google.com:80\r\n' +
                '\r\n');
socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
});
socket.end();
});
```

I get same error:

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1366:r20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:403:27)
```

Your help is welcome.

Comment: why would you want to write http requests manually !?!?

Comment: because i want to create http version 1.0 not 1.1, do you know a way to set request version on http.request?

Comment: sorry, never been there.

Answer (score 5):

`http.request` always uses HTTP/1.1, it's hardcoded in the source.

Here is the code to send HTTP/1.0 request using plain TCP stream (via `net.connect`):

```
var net = require('net');

var opts = {
  host: 'google.com',
  port: 80
}

var socket = net.connect(opts, function() {
  socket.end('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n' +
             'Host: google.com\r\n' +
              '\r\n');
});

socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```